# Same package-lock.json and git commit, but typescript detects errors

Tags: node.js, typescript, npm, package.json, nvm

I'm currently trying to develop a typescript project in Windows WSL2.

I downloaded my git project, and installed the npm environment on this WSL2 of Windows.
I did it with nvm. As our project has an .nvmrc with version 12.11.1, I use `nvm use` which gives me node version 12.11.1. I updated npm to its latest version (6.14.9), with `nvm install-latest-npm`.

This renders a system that uses the same npm and node versions as my other computers.

Now I run `npm install` in my root project directory, and after that, `npm run serve`, which launches the server.

How come, that having the same package-lock.json on all computers, and having the same npm and node versions (and of course, same code) I get typescript errors in launching server?

Is there any missing piece in my logic? Maybe some package that usually is not included in WSL?

Thank you in advance and sorry for the not so *to the point* question.

Comment: May be related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50799914/why-does-npm-install-generate-different-package-lock-json-files-for-the-same

Comment: sadly, same package-lock.json :(